# Python's barchart equivalent in R

Tags: python, r

the code below is from Udacity's Intro to Statistics

```
#Write a line of code to produce a barchart of Weight by groups of Height 
#using the barchart function

from plotting import *

Height=[65.78, 71.52, 69.4, 68.22, 67.79, 68.7, 69.8, 70.01, 67.9, 66.78,
66.49, 67.62, 68.3, 67.12, 68.28, 71.09, 66.46, 68.65, 71.23, 67.13, 67.83, 
68.88, 63.48, 68.42, 67.63, 67.21, 70.84, 67.49, 66.53, 65.44, 69.52, 65.81, 
67.82, 70.6, 71.8, 69.21, 66.8, 67.66, 67.81, 64.05, 68.57, 65.18, 69.66, 67.97, 
65.98, 68.67, 66.88, 67.7, 69.82, 69.09]

Weight=[112.99, 136.49, 153.03, 142.34, 144.3, 123.3, 141.49, 136.46, 
112.37, 120.67, 127.45, 114.14, 125.61, 122.46, 116.09, 140.0, 129.5, 142.97, 
137.9, 124.04, 141.28, 143.54, 97.9, 129.5, 141.85, 129.72, 142.42, 131.55, 
108.33, 113.89, 103.3, 120.75, 125.79, 136.22, 140.1, 128.75, 141.8, 121.23, 
131.35, 106.71, 124.36, 124.86, 139.67, 137.37, 106.45, 128.76, 145.68, 116.82, 
143.62, 134.93]

barchart(Height, Weight)
```

Below is the output

[image]

Executing this code returns a barchart demonstrating a linear relationship of height vs weight.

Is there anything equivalen in R?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect us to run Python to see how the barchart looks like? Btw. a barplot is probably not the best choice to illustrate a linear relationship. Also: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather do a simple scatter plot:

```
Height=c(65.78, 71.52, 69.4, 68.22, 67.79, 68.7, 69.8, 70.01, 67.9, 66.78,
        66.49, 67.62, 68.3, 67.12, 68.28, 71.09, 66.46, 68.65, 71.23, 67.13, 67.83, 
        68.88, 63.48, 68.42, 67.63, 67.21, 70.84, 67.49, 66.53, 65.44, 69.52, 65.81, 
        67.82, 70.6, 71.8, 69.21, 66.8, 67.66, 67.81, 64.05, 68.57, 65.18, 69.66, 67.97, 
        65.98, 68.67, 66.88, 67.7, 69.82, 69.09)

Weight=c(112.99, 136.49, 153.03, 142.34, 144.3, 123.3, 141.49, 136.46, 
        112.37, 120.67, 127.45, 114.14, 125.61, 122.46, 116.09, 140.0, 129.5, 142.97, 
        137.9, 124.04, 141.28, 143.54, 97.9, 129.5, 141.85, 129.72, 142.42, 131.55, 
        108.33, 113.89, 103.3, 120.75, 125.79, 136.22, 140.1, 128.75, 141.8, 121.23, 
        131.35, 106.71, 124.36, 124.86, 139.67, 137.37, 106.45, 128.76, 145.68, 116.82, 
        143.62, 134.93)

plot(Height, Weight)
```

[image]

But you can play around with the option `type` to have another type of plot. For example:

```
plot(Height, Weight, type="h")
```

---

EDIT: with the example plot, the question is maybe much clearer.

COMMENT: I think there is a lot of wasted information by doing that and that it does not illustrate well at all a linear link between the two variables...

Here is a proposition: I'm assuming that the ordered factor is based on height and that it is used to aggregate weights (by computing the mean of the weight of individuals whose height belong to a certain bin).

1. First create the ordered factor from variable `Height`:

   ```
   f <- cut(Height, 5, ordered_result = TRUE)
   ```
2. Based on this ordered factor, aggregate weights:

   ```
   y <- tapply(Weight, f, mean)
   ```
3. And plot:

   ```
   barplot(y, col="steelblue", border=NA, xlab="Height", ylab="Weight" )
   ```

[image]

Comment: My line of thinking is to create an ordered factor variable on height grouped into 5 bins and then plot that.

Comment: @chribonn in that case, you are looking for a histogram. See `?hist`.